# Using convolution kernel to blur a grey-scale image

Tags: java, blur, grayscale, convolution

I've only started learning java and I'm finding this particular section of my course very difficult.

Currently I have an assignment when I have a grey-scale image (in pnm format) that I have to blur by averaging 4 pixels into 1. I've read around about Convolution and Gaussian filters but can't seem to implement it into my code at all. It's the filter method after the kernel which is showing as an error but I can't seem to resolve it without messing up another section.

I'm just looking for some tips to help solve this. We've only just started the I/O and Patterns module so I apologise in advance for how basic my code is:

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImageOp;
import java.awt.image.ConvolveOp;
import java.awt.image.Kernel;
import java.io.*;

public class Picture
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    File picture1 = new File("ComputerScience-in.pnm");
    File picture2 = new File("blurredImage.pnm"); 

    BufferedReader in = (new BufferedReader(new FileReader(picture1)));
    BufferedWriter out = (new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(picture2)));

    float[] kernelMatrix = 
    {
            0.111f, 0.111f, 0.111f, 
            0.111f, 0.111f, 0.111f, 
            0.111f, 0.111f, 0.111f, 
    };

        BufferedImageOp op = new ConvolveOp(new Kernel(3, 3, kernelMatrix));
        Object blurredImage = op.filter(picture1, picture2);

    in.close();

    out.write(picture1 + "\n");

    out.close();

}


}
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What is the error message you are getting? According to the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/ConvolveOp.html#filter%28java.awt.image.BufferedImage,%20java.awt.image.BufferedImage%29) `op.filter` requires two `BufferedImage` instances and you are passing `File` here.

Comment: @LeonardBrünings I think I might have done this wrong. I don't need convolution filtering, I just need to put the image pixels into an array and then average blocks of 4 pixels into 1 so that the original image (2n x 2m) becomes blurred (n x m). I'll try to write that, but might need to ask a new questions. Thanks though.